# Hidden features in Bing

Tags: bing

Do you know of any hidden features in Bing or Bing Maps?

Answer (score 1):

Most of these features aren't exactly hidden, but about.com has a [Bing cheatsheet](http://websearch.about.com/library/blbingsearch.htm).

Some notable ones:

- Add **prefer:** to a keyword to place more importance on results having it.
- Use brackets to specify more complicated conditions: **malware or (virus and computer)**
- Add **intitle:** to a keyword to require results to have a word in the title.